# Evaluate string expression (R, Seurat)

Tags: r, string, evaluate

I'm trying to evaluate a string expression in the `subset()` function of the R Seurat package. https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/essential_commands.html

For example, instead of

```
subset(x = pbmc, subset = MS4A1 > 3)
```

I want to do

```
string.to.evaluate = "MS4A1 > 3"
subset(x = pbmc, subset = string.to.evaluate)
```

I know `eval(parse())` can sometimes be used to evaluate string expressions, but this fails since `MS4A1` is a rowname inside `pbmc`. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: For clarity, "MS4A1" is a rowname of the "counts" slot inside the S4 SeuratObject pbmc. In the Seurat package, there's a `subset` method for cleanly accessing and filtering SeuratObjects, and I'd like to call it dynamically by passing it strings.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a link to where you got that information?

Comment: Thank you! I'll wait for more answers, but feel free to put your comments into a question and I'll accept if there are no other answers.

Comment: Check the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
string.to.evaluate = "MS4A1 > 3"
subset(x = pbmc, !!str2lang(string.to.evaluate))
```

Example:

```
data(pbmc_small, package = "SeuratObject")
string.to.evaluate = "nCount_RNA>202"
subset(x = pbmc_small, !!str2lang(string.to.evaluate))

An object of class Seurat 
230 features across 36 samples within 1 assay 
Active assay: RNA (230 features, 20 variable features)
 2 dimensional reductions calculated: pca, tsne
```